# DisplayIndex Makes Button Move

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I use DisplayIndex to change JABATAN (from joining table) columns position, but column button in datagridview moves too.

**here's the ss.**

1. before i use DisplayIndex

[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/t6qzye.png[/IMG]

2. after i use DisplayIndex

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2dadk5d.png[/IMG]

**here's my code.**

1. before i use DisplayIndex

> dgvPegawai.DataSource = pegawaiM.tampilPegawai();
>
> ```
>             dgvPegawai.ReadOnly = true;
>
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDPEGAWAI"].HeaderText = "ID";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDJABATAN"].Visible = false;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMAJABATAN"].HeaderText = "JABATAN";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMALENGKAP"].HeaderText = "NAMA LENGKAP";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TEMPATLAHIR"].HeaderText = "TEMPAT";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TANGGALLAHIR"].HeaderText = "TANGGAL LAHIR";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["ALAMATLENGKAP"].HeaderText = "ALAMAT";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOKTP"].HeaderText = "NO. KTP";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOTELEPON"].HeaderText = "NO. TELEPON";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["USERNAME"].HeaderText = "USERNAME";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["PASSWORD"].Visible = false;
>
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDPEGAWAI"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMAJABATAN"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMALENGKAP"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TEMPATLAHIR"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TANGGALLAHIR"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["ALAMATLENGKAP"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOKTP"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOTELEPON"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["USERNAME"].Width = 150;
> ```

2. after i use DisplayIndex

> dgvPegawai.DataSource = pegawaiM.tampilPegawai();
>
> ```
>             dgvPegawai.ReadOnly = true;
>
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDPEGAWAI"].HeaderText = "ID";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDJABATAN"].Visible = false;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMAJABATAN"].HeaderText = "JABATAN";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMALENGKAP"].HeaderText = "NAMA LENGKAP";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TEMPATLAHIR"].HeaderText = "TEMPAT";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TANGGALLAHIR"].HeaderText = "TANGGAL LAHIR";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["ALAMATLENGKAP"].HeaderText = "ALAMAT";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOKTP"].HeaderText = "NO. KTP";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOTELEPON"].HeaderText = "NO. TELEPON";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["USERNAME"].HeaderText = "USERNAME";
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["PASSWORD"].Visible = false;
>
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDPEGAWAI"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMAJABATAN"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMALENGKAP"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TEMPATLAHIR"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TANGGALLAHIR"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["ALAMATLENGKAP"].Width = 205;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOKTP"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOTELEPON"].Width = 150;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["USERNAME"].Width = 150;
>
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["IDPEGAWAI"].DisplayIndex = 0;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMAJABATAN"].DisplayIndex = 1;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NAMALENGKAP"].DisplayIndex = 2;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TEMPATLAHIR"].DisplayIndex = 3;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["TANGGALLAHIR"].DisplayIndex = 4;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["ALAMATLENGKAP"].DisplayIndex = 5;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOKTP"].DisplayIndex = 6;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["NOTELEPON"].DisplayIndex = 7;
>             dgvPegawai.Columns["USERNAME"].DisplayIndex = 8;
> ```

this is the code i use to make button in the gridview

> ```
>         DataGridViewButtonColumn btnHapus = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
>         dgvPegawai.Columns.Add(btnHapus);
>         btnHapus.HeaderText = "";
>         btnHapus.Name = "btnDelete";
>         btnHapus.Text = "HAPUS";
>         btnHapus.Width = 55;
>         btnHapus.DisplayIndex = 12;
>         btnHapus.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
> ```

thx before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please post how(code) to create gridview component and table?
Or you can try below code

```
dataGridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```